# ¿Cómo listar un directorio completo a partir de una carpeta espcífica (no root)?

Tags: google-apps-script

Tengo un inconveniente para el que no he encontrado solución.

Tengo que copiar una archivo (el mismo archivo) en las carpetas finales de un árbol de directorios.

Para que quede más claro: La carpeta que hace las veces de raíz (**Escuela**), tiene varias subcarpetas (**Lenguajes**), que a su vez tienen más subcarpetas (**Años de cursada**), que contienen las carpetas correspondientes a cada materia. En cada una de esas carpetas debe ir un archivo *actas_de_examen.xlsx*.

Son alrededor de 250 carpetas, así que hacerlo manualmente sería un engorro.
Estoy intentando escribir el script, pero mi conocimiento es sumamente básico, así que trato de copiar y adaptar tutoriales.

Entiendo que este script debería listar todos los subdirectorios de la carpeta que se seleccione como raíz, pero no lo hace:

```
function copyFileRecursive() {  
  var rootFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("id-del-directorio-madre");
  var folders = rootFolder.getFolders();
  
  while(folders.hasNext()){      
    Logger.log(folders.next());
  }
}
```

Lo único que hace es listar en el Log los 10 directorios correspondientes al nivel 1 (**lenguajes**), pero no los niveles siguientes.

Si pudieran ayudarme a salvar este paso, creo que podré con el resto.

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta función te puede servir:

```
function listFolders(folder) {
  var folderName = folder.getName();
  Logger.log(folderName);

  /*subcarpetas*/
  var subfolders = folder.getFolders();

  /*Si tiene subcarpetas, llamada recursiva*/
  while (subfolders.hasNext()) {    
    listFolders(subfolders.next());
  }
}
```

Prueba:

```
folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("TU-FOLDER-ID-AQUI") 
listFolders(folder)
```

**Salida en el Log**

```
[20-11-20 23:21:14:401 CET] Bibliotecas
[20-11-20 23:21:14:615 CET] Santos
[20-11-20 23:21:14:832 CET] Vidas de los Santos por mes-Butler
[20-11-20 23:21:14:973 CET] Vidas de Santos en particular
[20-11-20 23:21:15:099 CET] Escritos de Santos
[20-11-20 23:21:15:244 CET] Lectio Divina Santos
[20-11-20 23:21:15:379 CET] Homilética
[20-11-20 23:21:15:562 CET] Santa Sede
[20-11-20 23:21:15:681 CET] San Agustín
[20-11-20 23:21:15:821 CET] Año Litúrgico-Patrístico (Bonaño)
[20-11-20 23:21:15:952 CET] Patrística
[20-11-20 23:21:16:153 CET] Autores Contemporáneos
[20-11-20 23:21:16:292 CET] Padres Griegos
[20-11-20 23:21:16:442 CET] San Cirilo de Jerusalén
[20-11-20 23:21:16:548 CET] San Gregorio de Nisa
[20-11-20 23:21:16:649 CET] Padres Latinos
[20-11-20 23:21:16:856 CET] San Cipriano
[20-11-20 23:21:16:960 CET] San Agustín-Obras Completas
...
```

Comment: ¡Genial! Funcionó muy bien. Muchas gracias, @ACedano